# In REST API, How to restrict URL access from browser using Nodejs & Expressjs

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express

I have a MEAN stack application and using  Node.js and Express.js as back-end API.

Assuming I have a 'comments' route as follow

```
/* GET /comments listing. */
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    Comment.find(function(err, comments) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(comments);
    });
});
```

And use it in my server like this:

```
var commentsRouter = require('./routes/comments');
...
app.use('/comments', commentsRouter);
```

My question is: Is there a way to prevent users to access `http://mrUrl/comments` in browser and deny the request with probably 403 Forbidden message but at the same time JavaScript file tries to access the same URL will receive a content message (in the example should be `res.json(comments);`)

Also, would it be possible to enable such a restriction for all routes once, not for each.

Comment: Javascript will run on browser, so you will get request from browser only. In order to prevent getting result in browser simply by putting url in address bar, you need to make this request as POST request.

Comment: What does "you need to make this request as POST request." mean? There are couple of route handlers and middlewares with different HTTp verbs for different models. I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: like the below example, router.post('\',handler). so that from browser address bar you can not get the data. Also you check for header in your incoming request to be sure like below example provided by @Omer Shukar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `middleware`.

A middleware is a function you can pass before or after the main function you are executing (in this case, `GET comments`)

the order of the function location matters, what comes first - executes first, and you implement it like so:

```
app.use(myBrowsingRestrictionMiddlewareFunction) // Runs 

app.use('/comments', commentsRouter);

app.use('/account', accountRouter);
```

You can also use within a `route handler`:

```
app.post('/comments', myMakeSureDataIsAlrightFunction, myMainCreateCommentFunction, myAfterStatusWasSentToClientAndIWishToMakeAnotherInternalActionMiddleware);
```

The properties `req, res, next` are passed into the function automatically.

which means, `myBrowsingRestrictionMiddlewareFunction` receives them and you can use them like so:

```
export function myBrowsingRestrictionMiddlewareFunction(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers['my-special-header']) {
     // custom header exists, then call next() to pass to the next function
     next();

  } else {
  
    res.sendStatus(403);      

  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Expanding regards to where to place the middleware in the FS structure (personal suggestion):

What I like to do is to separate the router from app.js like so:

*app.js*

```
app.use('/', mainRouter);
```

*router.js*

```
const router = express.Router();

router.use(middlewareForAllRoutes);

router.use('/comments', commentsRouter);

router.use(middlewareForOnlyAnyRouteBelow);

router.use('/account', accountRouter);

router.use(middlewareThatWillBeFiredLast); // To activate this, remember to call next(); on the last function handler in your route.
```

*commentsRouter.js*

```
const router = express.Router();

router.use(middlewareForAllRoutesONLYFORWithinAccountRoute);

route.get('/', middlewareOnlyForGETAccountRoute, getAccountFunction);

router.post('/', createAccount);
```

Comment: Using a middleware makes sense to me but I did not quite understand your route handler approach. 
however, would be 'my-special-header'? where myBrowsingRestrictionMiddlewareFunction should be located? in app.js(server.js) probably?

Comment: In case your route handlers are located in app.js, then YES, you place it in app.js, BEFORE the route handler itself. Also added my approach in the post

Comment: What is 'my-special-header'?

Comment: You can adjust your client side to generate a custom header for every request you send to the server. For instance, in `Angular`, you can use `HTTP Interceptor`. But you can achieve that with any other framework or pure JS, attaching a header of some value to `new XMLHttpRequest `

Comment: Setting header seems like a great way to validate requests to a server. However, would the headers being set in the client be able to be viewed by the public; such as with the ‘inspect’ element?